# Can't restore `mongodump` archivegz file with `mongorestore`

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I generated a MongoDB dump file with the `archivegz` format. When I try to restore it with the `mongorestore` command, it won't restore.

**The command for restore**

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive="./mongo_device.bing.com_20220209-000000.archivegz" --db=Test --verbose
```

**The result**

```
2022-02-10T11:57:02.955+0330    using write concern: &{majority false 0}
2022-02-10T11:57:03.587+0330    will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
2022-02-10T11:57:03.588+0330    connected to node type: standalone
2022-02-10T11:57:03.588+0330    The --db and --collection flags are deprecated for this use-case; please use --nsInclude instead, i.e. with --nsInclude=${DATABASE}.${COLLECTION}
2022-02-10T11:57:03.740+0330    archive prelude Logger.logs
2022-02-10T11:57:03.740+0330    archive prelude Logger.DeviceChannelData
2022-02-10T11:57:03.740+0330    archive format version "0.1"
2022-02-10T11:57:03.740+0330    archive server version "4.4.3"
2022-02-10T11:57:03.740+0330    archive tool version "v3.15.0_alpha20210804-4411-g6ef8a4d4d7"
2022-02-10T11:57:03.741+0330    preparing collections to restore from
2022-02-10T11:57:03.741+0330    skipping restoring Logger.logs, it is not included
2022-02-10T11:57:03.741+0330    skipping restoring Logger.logs metadata, it is not included
2022-02-10T11:57:03.742+0330    skipping restoring Logger.DeviceChannelData, it is not included
2022-02-10T11:57:03.742+0330    skipping restoring Logger.DeviceChannelData metadata, it is not included
2022-02-10T11:57:04.208+0330    demux finishing (err:<nil>)
2022-02-10T11:57:04.208+0330    received  from namespaceChan
2022-02-10T11:57:04.208+0330    restoring up to 4 collections in parallel
2022-02-10T11:57:04.208+0330    building indexes up to 4 collections in parallel
2022-02-10T11:57:04.208+0330    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
2022-02-09T13:50:42.321+0330    preparing collections to restore from
2022-02-09T13:50:42.755+0330    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Comment: Try with `--verbose` option. Usually extension is just `.gz`, not `archivegz`. Did you manipulate the dump?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I add verbose flag, Updated result

Comment: How did you create the dump?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I use the command like this `mongodump --archive="test.archivegz" --gzip`

Comment: Try filename with extension `.gz` (not `.archivegz`) According to https://linux.die.net/man/1/gunzip the unzip tool does not like other extensions: "*gunzip takes a list of files on its command line and replaces each file whose name ends with .gz, -gz, .z, -z, _z or .Z*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in incorrectly setting the `--db` flag. When the flag is removed, the `mongorestore` restores the data. Use the command as described below.

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive="./mongo_device.bing.com_20220209-000000.archivegz"
```